# JSON submission being parsed as XML?

Tags: json, c#, xml

I'm trying to submit a lead into the system using the username-password model.  The authentication is now playing nicely, but when I get to the stage of actually trying to get the lead into the system, I'm getting back an error that doesn't seem to make much sense:

```
[{"errorCode":"APEX_ERROR","message":"System.XmlException: Failed to parse XML due to: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1) \n\nClass.LendingTreeWS.createNewLead: line 10, column 1"}]
```

This appears to be an XML error, but I'm submitting JSON data, and everything I see suggests it should be working just fine.  I've tried now four or five different web submission methods in case there's something strange in the headers, but I'm not seeing any actual problem.  The snippet that's performing the actual submission is:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + oCred.accessToken);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

string resultCode = "";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(post_data);
}
try
{
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        resultCode = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()).ToString();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // handler here
    if (ex.Response != null)
    {
        // can use ex.Response.Status, .StatusDescription
        if (ex.Response.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    ServiceLogUpdate(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing changes if I alter the JSON (which is stored in post_data, and is a tested and valid JSON string).  If I try with empty content, I get an "input contained no data" error -- which is fine, makes sense -- but nothing else I can do helps or changes anything.  I considered just changing the whole thing over to XML, but that doesn't seem to work because many of the field-names I've been provided for this integration are prefixed 00 (along the lines of 00ABC000000qwER, and so on), which makes them invalid for XML, and they get rejected by the receiving XML parser.

Has anyone run into anything like this -- or does anyone have any solution for how to submit those numerically-prefixed fields to SalesForce in XML?  It's driving me up the wall today -- the headers seem to be right, but the error suggests that SalesForce wants to interpret the submission as XML instead of JSON, and I can't for the life of me see why it would be doing that when the content-type header's set to application/json.

Comment: I don't believe salesforce is doing this. Can you give us line 10 of the class LendingTreeWS? ... Well, probably that and a few lines surrounding it? I don't believe this code is the problem specifically, but how the Apex Code for it was written.

Comment: Ah, I should have noticed that!  I don't have access to the LendingTreeWS class -- I didn't write it --but it will explain a lot of the problems here!  I know who to contact about this now, anyway -- thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Well, glad I could help!